# Looping through multiple variables in javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I can't get my head around the following and was hoping if someone can send me into the right direction.

For social media analytics I want to create a scatter chart that shows the number of likes you've received by day and hour so that you can get an idea of what a good time is to post to social media.

I got an array of objects with all the info of each post such as: day(0-6), what hour(0-23), number of likes. Looking like this:

```
var posts_array = [{caption: "hello", day: 0, hours: 2 ,likes:200},
                {caption: "hello2", day: 0, hours: 1, likes: 100}];
```

In order to plot the scatter chart I need to end up with an array of objects looking like this:

```
var array_objects = [{day: 0, hours:0, sum_of_likes: somenumber},{day:0,
           hours:1, sum_of_likes: somenumber}]
```

My plan was to create an array of objects with day, hour and sum of likes. And then loop through each post, day and hour and add the number of likes to the correct object.

So far I got this:

```
//create array of objects for each day and hour
var array_objects = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 24; j++) {
        var object = new Object();
        object.day = i;
        object.likes = 0;
        object.timeslot = j;
        array_objects.push(object);

    }
}

//loop through each day and hours

for (var i = 0; i < posts_array.length; i++) { //loop through all posts

    for (var j = 0; j < 7; j++) { //loop through each day
        if (posts_array[i].day == j){ 
            for (var k = 0; k < 24; k++) { //loop through each hour of day
                if(posts_array[i].hours == k){

                    //how to get object reference?
                }   
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

But I struggle to find the reference of the object at the end. I also wonder whether this is the right approach anyway as it seems a bit of tedious way of doing it.

Comment: There is not `posts_array` declared before the `for loop`.

Comment: Sorry you're right, just updated the post. posts_array is the array that includes all the posts - see example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to combine the data as you go along. You can create a dictionary of dictionaries for this purpose.

```
array_objects = {}
for (var i = 0; i < posts_array.length; i++) {
    var temp = post_array[i]
    if array_objects[temp.day+"_"+temp.hours] {
        array_objects[temp.day+"_"+temp.hours][sum_of_likes] += temp.likes
    } else {
        array_objects[temp.day+"_"+temp.hours] = {day: temp.day, hours: temp.hours, sum_of_likes: temp.likes}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no idea whether this is the most efficient way of doing it but it definitely works for me. Thanks for you help!

Comment: There are ways to simplify this code; for example, juvian's code removes the need to store keys and values, which would save space and time. However, that requires you to have values for each hour of each day, so depending on your data, creating a dictionary may be more efficient. In addition, it is generally more efficient to combine data as you read it instead of creating two loops, one to read data and one to combine data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as your array_objects is 1 dimentional and with the way you made it, you can do :

```
if(posts_array[i].hours == k){
    var reference = array_objects[j * 24 + k];
}
```

Still, its much better to do :

```
for (var i = 0; i < posts_array.length; i++) {
    var reference = array_objects[posts_array[i].day * 24 + posts_array[i].hours];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, I would suggest the following:

```
let scatter_objects = [];
Array.prototype.forEach.call(post_array, (post)=>{
    let keys = Object.keys(post);
    keys.forEach((key, index, array)=>{
        // the arguments are passed for each post object; array is the original post object
       // here key is the property like day, hour, likes
       // you can now filter each post by key and return an object that 
       // the end result would be a filtered object pushed to the 
       // scatter_objects array
       // at the end,
       scatter_objects.push(processed_object);
    });

});
```